# Android BLE enable notification

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project which includes the interaction with a BLE button like this: [image]

My problem is that I don't know how can I do to enable the notification once that user press ble button. In this moment this method onCharacteristicChanged never fires.

```
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        //read the characteristic data
        byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("ISFROMBLE", true);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Could you please help me? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to discover your beacon, then check the UUID of this BLE Button and if it matches, then fire onCharacteristicChanged() or send a notification.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, but I don't understand how can I do this.
I'm able to connect the device ble but after I don't find a way to get the UUID of this BLE...

Answer (score 2):

You are skipping lots of steps in connecting to a BLE device properly.

See the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Assuming that you have set up your connection correctly and onServicesDiscovered is called, after discovering services you need to enable notification on the desired characteristic:

```
characteristic = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(SERVICE_UUID)).getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)); //Find you characteristic
mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true); //Tell you gatt client that you want to listen to that characteristic
List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> descriptors = characteristic.getDescriptors(); //find the descriptors on the characteristic
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = descriptors.get(1); //get the right descriptor for setting notifications
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor); //apply these changes to the ble chip to tell it we are ready for the data
```

and then onCharacteristicChanged is called whenever that characteristic changes.

Comment: in descriptors. get() you should get the number 0 instead of 1, because there is a possibility that there is only 1 descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You might have got your beacon sdk or jar. Include that to your android project. now in your eclipse project -

```
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer,
RangeNotifier {
//Add all unimplemented methods
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.bind(this);
 } 

@Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons,
            final Region region) {
     Beacon beacon = (Beacon) iterator.next();

                        uuid = beacon.getId1().toUuidString();
                        major = beacon.getId2().toInt();
                         //get your id and match with your ble button. If it matches, then you can call your method or send a notification
}
}
```